# How do I create a filled area plot with the colored area *above* the trace with Plotly Javascript?

Tags: plot, area, plotly.js

Plotly has a feature "area plots" which allow you to fill the area below a plot with a certain color and opacity, up to the next lower trace or zero, or group of traces. See https://plot.ly/javascript/filled-area-plots/

I want to reverse this. I want to fill the area *above* the trace, up to infinity basically. How can I do this with Plotly directly?

So far I have only seen workarounds and hacks (color the whole plot background and then color the area below the trace white, or flipping the entire plot, etc) that have serious problems for my application, such as the grid not being visible below the trace or other traces being obscured. For example, this - but it requires a third trace (trace 1) a Y=1000 with the orange fill below it, and a white fill *below* the actual "trace 0" which isn't what I want.
[image: Example]

Can the fill be moved above a trace directly with Plotly, or can Plotly be patched to allow this rather easily, without having to create "pseudo" additional traces with very high Y values, or changing the plot area background color or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do that is creating a new "invisible" line above and defining fill='tonextx'. This will fill from your line to the one you have previously defined (the "invisible" one).

So, in you case, you could draw a white line in y=10, and x within the range you want, say:

```
##Adding a white line (assuming the plot was already created) on the top of the plot## 
  %>%add_trace(
  x = c(1,4), 
  y = 10,
  line=list(color='#ffffff'),
  mode = 'lines'
)
##Adding the desired line and filling it to the top## 

%>%add_trace(
  x = #x of your line#, 
  y = #y of your line#,
  line=list(color='#000000'),
  mode = 'lines',
  fill = 'tonextx'
)
```

This should fill the area above your line to the line in x=c(1,4) and y=10